# Installing xgboost on Arch Linux through cmake

Tags: machine-learning, cmake, pip, xgboost, archlinux

I am trying to install xgboost through the git repositorty, using the following commands

```
cd xgboost
mkdir build
cd build 
cmake ..
```

When I run the last command `cmake..` I get the following error message

```
-- CMake version 3.25.0
-- xgboost VERSION: 2.1.0
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:227 (add_subdirectory):
  The source directory

    /mnt/32F6E6CAF6E68D83/Downloads/xgboost/dmlc-core

  does not contain a CMakeLists.txt file.


CMake Error at cmake/Utils.cmake:198 (set_target_properties):
  set_target_properties Can not find target to add properties to: dmlc
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:307 (xgboost_target_properties)


CMake Error at cmake/Utils.cmake:270 (target_link_libraries):
  Cannot specify link libraries for target "dmlc" which is not built by this
  project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:308 (xgboost_target_link_libraries)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/mnt/32F6E6CAF6E68D83/Downloads/xgboost/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Answer (score 2):

If you downloaded the tarball from the website it doesn't contain the git submodules (e.g. dmlc-core; see https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/3594 for further discussion).

Do you get the same error if you use these steps?

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost
git submodule init
git submodule update

cd xgboost
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make -j$(nproc)
```